# How to input features seperately to LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to use LSTM for my timeseries classification problem as follows. My dataset has about 2000 datapoints and each data point is having 25 length 4 timeseries.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(25,4)))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, the LSTM model works very poorly and gives me very low results. While this is upsetting, I am thinking that LSTM provides low results as it is unable to capture some imporatant characteristics from the timeseries.

In that case, I am wondering if it is possible to give some handcrafted features along with the timeseries to the model? If so, please let me know how to do it.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

EDIT:
I am thinking if it is possible to use kera's functional API in this regard. So that, I can I can use my features as a seperate input.

Comment: have you tried modifying the input dataset itself? You can try mapping the data onto some higher dimension and pass this new mapped data to your LSTM. I am not sure if it would help, but I can't do much without some data or what accuracy you're getting...

Comment: @Hiten do you mean mapping my time-series to something else. For instance my timeseries looks as follows [0.9, 0.8. 0.12, ...., 0.88] etc. Please let me know how I can map this into a higher dimension :)

Comment: Use a kernel function of some sort... if your attributes right now are x1,x2,...,xN, and you think that maybe x1*x2 or x1*x2*x3 is a better feature, then just append these values to your data, and use this new dataset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSTM model takes-in a 3-dimensional tensor as an input with dimensions `(batch-size, time-length, num-features)`.

To answer your question, you will have to concatenate those hand-crafted features along with these four raw features that you have, may be normalize them to bring all of them to the same scale, and pass a `(batch-size, time-length, features+x)` as an input to the LSTM model.